# Implementing SSO between two WSO2 tenants

Tags: cloud, single-sign-on, saml, wso2

I'm trying to implement an SSO solution on WSO2 between multiple tentants. Is this possible? If so, what kind of optoins should I be looking into?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible OOTB currently. But this is possible with a custom SAML2 authenticator. Check the existing SAML2 SSO authenticator here.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0/components/authenticators/saml2-sso-authenticator/

But IMO, this is fairly complex. How do you define which users can authenticate to which tenants ?

-- Thilina

Comment: thanks.  The intent is to allow all users access to each tenant, but maybe restrict the user to certain content based on their entitlements.

Comment: Probably you can maintain users in a higher level without associating them with a tenant, and then write custom authenticator to associate the tenant when they are logged into the service.